# how to assign a list value to column in excel file?

Tags: python, excel, pandas, openpyxl, xlsxwriter

I have a list value and want to assign it into a column in a excel file. The values I want to change are in sheet 6.

my poor code looks something like this the best I could do is try to first change the AF6:AF22 to a fixed value 5 with hope that I could change it to list.

But is there a simple way to change AF6:AF22 values to a list?
something simple ws['AF6:AF22'] = l?

```
from openpyxl import Workbook
import pandas as pd
from openpyxl import load_workbook

l = list(range(5))

FilePath = 'excel_file.xlsx'
wb = load_workbook(FilePath)

ws = wb.worksheets

sheet_number = 6 

for sheet_number in ws.iter_cols('AF6:AF22'):
    for cell in sheet_number:
        cell.value = 5
```

Comment: Hi @helpme - Trying to understand your question.... you have a python list with 17 items in it. You want those 17 items to be updated in excelLfile.xlsx > Sheet6 > cells AF6 to AF22. Is this what you are trying to do?

Comment: @Redox you are correct

Comment: You use `sheet_number` to refer rows and worksheets. This is bound to be confusing. You assign the same value to every cell.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Option 1**
Hi - I am adding a faster way here. This is probably better as it avoids the for loop and updating cells one at a time.

```
from openpyxl import Workbook
import pandas as pd
from openpyxl import load_workbook

l = list(range(17))  #The list - You can replace l with whatever you need

with pd.ExcelWriter('excel_file.xlsx', mode='a', engine = 'openpyxl') as writer: 
    pd.DataFrame(l).to_excel(writer, sheet_name='Sheet6', startrow = 5, startcol= 31, index=False, header=None)
```

**Option 2**
You can use the below code to do what you need. Added comments, so you get an understanding of my logic...

```
from openpyxl import Workbook
import pandas as pd
from openpyxl import load_workbook

l = list(range(17))  #The list - You can replace l with whatever you need

FilePath = 'excel_file.xlsx'
wb = load_workbook(FilePath)

ws = wb.worksheets[5]  #Worksheet 5 is the 6th sheet as numbering starts from zero
for i in range(6,23):  # Column numbers 6 through 22
    ws.cell(row=i, column=32).value = l[i-6]  #Write to cell in AF = column 32
    
wb.save("excel_file.xlsx")
```

Comment: Ugh! Just zip over the rows and the list.

Comment: Hi @CharlieClark - Based on your feedback, I figured out a way to avoid the FOR loop, thus reducing the complexity from `O(N)` to `O(1)` :-). But, I am still not sure why we would need `zip`. As the list is provided, assuming user has other code which will crate the list. So, not sure if the zip is much use, as it still would mean we have to go, row by row?

Comment: You're going row by row anyway. If you use `zip` you avoid the need for a counter, which is often a problem. `for row, v in zip(ws.iter_rows(min_row=6, max_row=22, min_col=23, max_col=23): row[0].value = v`

Comment: Oh Wow !!! Thanks @CharlieClark. Certainly did not think of it :-)

Comment: The Openpyxl API usually means you don't have to reinvent the wheel and you should almost never need your own counters.

Comment: You make an incorrect assumption about speed: Pandas won't be faster because you are going to have convert the dataframe to openpyxl cells one by one anyway.

Comment: Thanks for correcting me @CharlieClark. I was not aware of it. Didn't realize Pandas used Openpyxl under the hood :-)